# Grouping rows in a column and descending

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzkB8.png)

Not sure how to ask this question correctly but how can I find the countries ("Team") with the most participants("Team"). Ranging from highest number of countries to least. For example United States 1000, China 999, etc.

Comment: provide an example, with data please.   That is: expected input *and* output

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df['Team'].value_counts()` to show the frequency of the team members belonging to different teams... by default it shows data in descending order.
To get in ascending order you can use: `df['Team'].value_counts(ascending=True)`